# Emailing database not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

!!I've realized the problem is with the email, it doesn't do what I thought it does. I want to schedule the email to happen everyday so it needs to be automatic. !!

I want to send a copy of the database in an email and I've read that I need to export the file into the SD card then be able to email it and this is what I've done but i get a "no apps perform this action" error when I try to run it. I'm using the android emulator that does have SD enabled.

```
public void sendEmail(View view){

    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Daily Records");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ "someemail@yahoo.com"});
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    FileChannel source=null;
    FileChannel destination=null;
    String DB_NAME = "inoutDB.db";
    String currentDBPath = "/data/"+ "mypackagename" +"/databases/"+DB_NAME;
    String backupDBPath = DB_NAME;
    File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
    File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        source.close();
        destination.close();
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(backupDB));
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send Email"));
}
```

I've added the permission part in my manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: you don't have access to data files

Comment: how can i get access to the data files?

Comment: you should ask this question to admin.

Comment: If you have not done so already, you are also going to need [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). And `targetSdkVersion="15"` is pretty old!

Answer (score 0):

String currentDBPath = "/data/"+ "mypackagename" +"/databases/"+DB_NAME;

This is wrong.  First the path is wrong (apps are generally installed in /data/data, although an OEM could decide to change that).  Secondly, you should never assume paths in Android-  use context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).